# Approximating continuous function by the span of $\{\sin(nx)\}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $f $ be continuous function on $[0,2\pi ]$ and $\int_0^{2\pi} f(x) \sin(nx) \, dx =0$ for all $n$ then prove that $f$ is identically zero.

Some of my friends claim that it is not true just because $\operatorname{span}\{\sin(nx)\}$ is not an algebra, but I am not convinced because I have seen odd power polynomial approximate continuous functions 
through the origin. And it is similar to that problem but I am able to see the right one. Please could you help me?

Comment: Try $f = \cos$ for a counterexample. Indeed, Try $f=k$, where $k$ is any constant. Or any 'even' function, where 'even' means $f(x) = f(2 \pi -x)$. Look at Fourier series.

Comment: ya i am convinced, it is wrong, is that problem need some modification? Why they write such wrong problem in qualifying exam?

Comment: Maybe you misread the problem?

Comment: Could be that the domain of integration is $[0, \pi]$?

Comment: No, i copied from the exam. Is it true in $[0,\pi]?$

Comment: @Lusin I think so. If the domain is $[0, \pi]$, then the integral is the coefficient of the Fourier sine series matching the odd extension of $f$.

Comment: @Lusin yes; the set 
$$
\left\{\sum_{n=0}^k a_n \sin(n x): k \in \mathbb{N}\right\}
$$
is an algebra that separates points over $[0,\pi]$

Comment: If you use $\{\sin(nx),\cos(nx) : n=0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$ then it's true, and it's an interesting result. ($\sin(0x)$ is not needed, but $\cos(0x)$ is.) ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: To correct my previous comment, the algebra I gave separates points, but does not *strongly* separate points, making it insufficient.  In particular, every function is zero at $x = 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your friends are right. $\sin(x/2)$ is orthogonal to $\sin(nx)$ for $n=1,2,3,\cdots$, and $\sin(x/2)$ is not identically $0$. The correct $\sin$ functions are
$$
        \sin(x/2),\sin(x),\sin(3x/2),\sin(2x),\cdots.
$$
This is a complete orthogonal subset of $L^{2}[0,2\pi]$ (orthonormal when properly normalized.)